# Understanding derivation of Wigner function for the Harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform

In the document https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf, they derive the Wigner functions, $f_n$ for the harmonic oscillator. However, I have some problems understanding some of the steps. On page 37 they write the equation:
$$\tag{1}
\left(\left(x+\frac{i \hbar}{2} \partial_{p}\right)^{2}+\left(p-\frac{i \hbar}{2} \partial_{x}\right)^{2}-2 E\right) f(x, p)=0
$$
Defining $z\equiv \frac{4}{\hbar}H= \frac{2}{\hbar}\left(x^{2}+p^{2}\right)$ they say that the real part of eq. $(1)$ can be written:
$$\tag{2}
\left(\frac{z}{4}-z \partial_{z}^{2}-\partial_{z}-\frac{E}{\hbar}\right) f(z)=0$$
and by setting $f(z)=\exp (-z / 2) L(z)$ we get Laguerre's equation:
$$\tag{3}
\left(z \partial_{z}^{2}+(1-z) \partial_{z}+\frac{E}{\hbar}-\frac{1}{2}\right) L(z)=0$$
Solved by Laguerre polynomials:
$$\tag{4}
L_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \frac{(-z)^{k}}{k !}$$
and the Wigner functions are then:
$$\tag{5}
f_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\pi \hbar} e^{-z/2} L_{n}\left(z\right)$$

There are 3 things that I do not get:

1. We can write the real part of eq. $(1)$ as $\left(x^{2}-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{4} \partial_{p}^{2}+p^{2}-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{4} \partial_{x}^{2}-2 E\right) f=0$. How is eq. $(2)$ obtained from this? (I don't get the $z \partial_{z}^{2}-\partial_{z}$ term)
2. How is eq. $(3)$ obtained from eq. $(2)$?
3. where does the $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\pi \hbar}$ pre-factor in eq. $(5)$ come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Product support.

1. Recall, crucially,  *f* was shown to be a function of *z only*, *f(z)*, so, acting on it,
   $$\partial_x = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x } \partial_z  \leadsto \\
   \partial_x^2 = \left (\partial_x \frac{\partial z}{\partial  x } \right )\partial_z  + \left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x }\right )^2  \partial_z^2 ~ ,
   $$
   and similarly for *y*, so that $\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 = 8(\partial_z + z\partial_z^2)/\hbar$.
2. You've been there before with the integrating factor of the oscillator equation to Hermite's in Hilbert space. Analogously,
   $$
   \left(\frac{z}{4}-z \partial_{z}^{2}-\partial_{z}-\frac{E}{\hbar}\right) ( e^{-z / 2}~L(z) )=0, ~~~~~\leadsto\\
    e^{-z / 2}
    \left(z \partial_{z}^{2}+(1-z) \partial_{z}+\frac{E}{\hbar}-\frac{1}{2}\right) L(z)=0.$$
   But the exponential can never be zero, and can thus be dropped.
3. Any multiple of these polynomials will solve this linear equation.
   However, it is practical/convenient to simplify their [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials)
   $$L_n(z)=\frac{e^z}{n!}\partial_z^n \left(e^{-z} z^n\right) =\frac{1}{n!} \left( \partial_z -1 \right)^n z^n,$$
   and Sheffer sequence recursive formula,
   $$
   \tag{7} \partial_z L_n = \left (  \partial_z - 1 \right ) L_{n-1},$$ generating function, etc, as you probably learned  from your Hydrogen atom. So they are all unity at the origin. Recall, from the text,  these are all ingredients of Wigner functions *f* normalized to 1, whence the common normalization; trivially checkable for *n=0*,
   $$
   1=\int\!\! dxdp ~f(z)= \frac{\pi \hbar }{2}\int_0^\infty\!\! dz ~e^{-z/2} L_n (z)\frac{(-)^n}{\pi \hbar} ~.
   $$
   But from *n=0* and the Sheffer sequence recursion (7), you may readily check the normalization for *n=1*, through integration by parts to be a mere change of sign. So, recursively, for all *n*, you show the alternating sign normalizations.

Comment: I get point 2 and 3 now. But I am still a bit lost on point 1. Is the following argument correct: $\partial f=\partial z \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?
And I do not see how you get the expression for $\partial_x^2$. As far as I know, the square of the product of two operators is the product of the squares, so I would assume $\partial_{x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \partial_{z} \Rightarrow \partial_{x}^{2}=\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^{2} \partial_{z}^{2}$

Comment: Notice in my first equation in the comment I use notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\partial_{x}$, so my denominator is not the same as the one you wrote above.

Comment: @Physics101 You have to apply the product rule, check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313764/changing-variable-in-a-second-derivative
and apply it here.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)\\
=\left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right) +\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}\right)\\
$$

Comment: @Physics101
$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}\rightarrow  \frac{\partial^2 z }{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks @Hans , I couldn't have said it better. I corrected my TeX-typos

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Hans Wurst. And thank you very much for the answers to my questions @CosmasZachos.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I tried to write an answer but product support was too fast and actually solved the problem :). But its nice that i've got some use out of my answer draft after all.

Comment: Thanks, I was out to lunch, so your comment was just the ticket!